# Is there a way to plot lines over a datashader plot in Bokeh (Python)?

Tags: python, bokeh, datashader

I am working with relatively large datasets (approximately 10x20.000.000 data point), for which Datashader is a useful visualisation tool. To give more information in these visualisations, I would like to add lines showing averages/standarddeviations on top of this datashade figure. Does anyone know how this would be possible?

My current code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show

x = 'xcol'
y= 'ycol'
data = dataframe

fig = figure(x_axis_label=x, y_axis_label=y)
points = hv.Points(data[[x, y]], label=('Title'))
hd.datashade(points, cmap='crest')
```

What I would like to do is for example add the following line to the figure generated with the code above:

```
fig.line([1,10,20], [0, 1000,2000], line_width=4)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be a lot easier for people to answer this question if it included runnable code; the above is just a sketch mixing Bokeh and (apparently) HoloViews code rather than something that would run. Assuming you are using HoloViews and you have successfully gotten a plot from `hd.datashade(points, cmap='crest')`, then you can overlay a horizontal line at e.g. y=5.6 using `import holoviews as hv` and then `hd.datashade(points, cmap='crest') * hv.HLine(5.6)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped me overlay datashader plots with lines and other objects. For future purposes I will post runnable codes with a dummy dataset.